# Speeding up a large number of SELECT queries which may or may not return a result

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have this query:

**"SELECT SECURITY_ID FROM " + securitiesTable + " WHERE (ISIN = ? or CUSIP = ? or SEDOL = ?)"**

I need to execute it about 50k times. Rows may have 1, 2, or all 3 of the values in the where clause, and some of the queries will return no results. For rows that come back I need to know which ISIN/CUSIP/SEDOL they match, and I need to know which ones have no results so I can insert them into the table later.

It's very slow right now, I'm assuming because of the round trip time of making 50k queries individually. Is there any way I can do this in a batch while keeping track of which query the results are for, and which queries have a null result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing 50k selects, create a temporary table, bulk load your ISINs, CUSIPs and SEDOLs into it and then `join` on that table. Then fetch the results in one go. This results in three network transfers instead of 50k.

Alternatively, restructure your statement into `... where ISIN in ('DE...','DE...',...)`, but most queries can't exceed 32k bytes length as the query string. This approach would need some batching still.

Also, ideally, the list of your securities already lives in the database, so you can either select them into the temporary table or directly join the securitiesTable to the rest of the information.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. I wish I'd thought of it. Thank you!